# Gitlab upgrade error init.d directory or file issue

Tags: git, unicorn, gitlab, sidekiq

Why am I getting this error?

Upgrading Git 5.4 to 6.0 On Cents 6.4

Followed upgrade guide 
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/5.4-to-6.0.md

After complete I try staring I git

Starting the GitLab Unicorn web server...

```
/etc/init.d/gitlab: line 131: script/web: No such file or directory
```

Starting the GitLab Sidekiq event dispatcher...

```
/etc/init.d/gitlab: line 139: script/background_jobs: No such file or directory
```

GitLab is not running.

In the `init.d` gitlab file

```
+    119 # Starts Unicorn and Sidekiq.  
+    120 start() {  
+    121   check_stale_pids  
+    122   
+    123   # Then check if the service is running. If it is: don't start again.  
+    124   if [ "$web_status" = "0" ]; then  
+    125     echo "The Unicorn web server already running with pid $wpid, not restarting."  
+    126   else  
+    127     echo "Starting the GitLab Unicorn web server..."  
+    128     # Remove old socket if it exists  
+    129     rm -f "$socket_path"/gitlab.socket 2>/dev/null  
+    130     # Start the webserver  
+    131     RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV script/web start  
+    132   fi  
+    133   
+    134   # If sidekiq is already running, don't start it again.  
+    135   if [ "$sidekiq_status" = "0" ]; then    
+    136     echo "The Sidekiq job dispatcher is already running with pid $spid, not restarting"  
+    137   else    
+    138     echo "Starting the GitLab Sidekiq event dispatcher..."  
+    139     RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV script/background_jobs start  
+    140     # We are sleeping a bit here because sidekiq is slow at writing it's pid  
+    141     sleep 2  
+    142   fi
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably You  are trying to use a newer version of the init script (ex. your version of gitlab is 6.0 and you are using init script from 6.2)

Try to copy oryginal version of init.d script from your installed version. Enter in console by root:

```
cp {GITLAB_HOME}/gitlab/lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab && chmod 755 /etc/init.d/gitlab && /etc/init.d/gitlab start
```

Of course change `{GITLAB_HOME}` to place where you have installed gitlab.